# Sanitize innerHTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, sanitize

I am using that block of code and bring told by a code validator that this should be sanitized.

What is wrong with it and how can i sanitize it?

```
el1 = document.getElementById('quote'); //this is fine
el1.innerHTML = quoteNew; //this should be sanitized
```

Comment: Where does `quoteNew` come from?

Comment: If it is supposed to be just text, then the safe way is `el1.textContent = quoteNew;`

Comment: quoteNew is a string with some css added to it

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli : It works!. Please make an answer so that I can choose your answer as best answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the contents of `quoteNew` are just text to display, then use the `textContent` property of the element.

```
 el1.textContent = quoteNew;
```

Comment: What if I need to display HTML?

Comment: @S.W.G. then you need to sanitize it according to your requirements. That is if you do not know where the contents of `quoteNew` are coming and if they are safe to render.

Comment: In my case contant comes from HTTPS request to my server, the only case it could be injected malicious content is if the user connects using bad WiFi so to exclude MITM attack I found a library to sanitize it, just to be extra safe.